# Segmentation fault when using qsort

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, qsort

I am working on a [c](/questions/tagged/c) program to read from a `txt` file and sort the strings.

**data.txt:**

```
jk ef ab cd bc gh fg ij hi de
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int cmp(const void *p1, const void *p2) {
    return strcmp(*(const char **)p1,  *(const char **)p2);
}

int main() {
    FILE *f = fopen("data.txt", "r");
    char s[255][255];
    char tmp[255];
    int n = 0;

    while (!feof(f)) {
        fscanf(f, "%s", tmp);
        strcpy(s[n], tmp);
        n++;
    }

    fclose(f);

    qsort(s, n, sizeof(char *), cmp);

    int i = 0;
    for (; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%s ", s[i]);
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I ran the code on Ubuntu and it breaks on a segfault. Believe this segfault happened in `qsort` and I could not figure out why.

Anyone can give me some suggestions?

Comment: 1) `sizeof(char *)`  --> `sizeof(*s)`

Comment: I tried but this does not solve it. Still seeing segfault.

Comment: 2) `return strcmp( *(const char **) p1,  *(const char **) p2);` --> `return strcmp( (const char *) p1,  (const char *) p2);`

Comment: 3) [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)....) then **use the debugger** (e.g. `gdb`). Read carefully the documentation of [qsort(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/qsort.3.html). Use [C dynamic memory allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: Re 2.: Are you sure?

Comment: @alk I think so.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: `qsort()` passes to the compare function pointers to the array's elements. The array's elements are `char[255]`. So `qsort()` compare function gets passed in two `char(*)[255]`.

Comment: @alk Eventually that head address is passed to the comparison function. E.g like `strcmp(s[X], s[Y])`

Comment: @alk The compare function will be passed pointers that point to the beginning of the elements. Each element contains a string, so casting the pointers to `(char*)` yields correct results.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The comparison function is incorrect, as you are sorting an array of arrays of `char`, you can pass the pointers to the elements to `strcmp` directly:

```
int cmp(const void *p1, const void *p2) {
    return strcmp(p1, p2);
}
```

Note however that your parsing loop is also incorrect: `feof()` is not the correct way to check for end of file. Use this instead:

```
  n = 0;
  while (n < 255 && fscanf(f, "%254s", s[n]) == 1) {
      n++;
  }
```

The `qsort` invokation should specify the size of the array element:

```
  qsort(s, n, sizeof(*s), cmp);
```

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int cmp(const void *p1, const void *p2) {
    return strcmp(p1, p2);
}

int main(void) {
    FILE *f = fopen("data.txt", "r");
    char s[255][255];
    char tmp[255];
    int n = 0;

    if (f == NULL)
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    while (n < 255 && fscanf(f, "%254s", s[n]) == 1) {
        n++;
    }
    fclose(f);

    qsort(s, n, sizeof(*s), cmp);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%s ", s[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Many people gave a good answer.

Here is how you could have found it by yourself, **step by step**, with standard GNU tools:

We suppose the source file is named `q.c`.

Compile with debugging symbols (note that no need to have a Makefile here):

```
% make CFLAGS=-g q
cc -g  q.c  -o q
```

Now, run the program with a debugger (gdb):

```
% gdb q
(gdb) run
Starting program: /usr/home/fenyo/tmp/qs/q
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000008009607a6 in strcmp () from /lib/libc.so.7
```

Now look at the stack frame:

```
(gdb) where
#0  0x00000008009607a6 in strcmp () from /lib/libc.so.7
#1  0x00000000004009b5 in cmp (p1=0x7ffffffeeb60, p2=0x7ffffffeeb88) at q.c:8
#2  0x000000080093b834 in qsort () from /lib/libc.so.7
#3  0x0000000000400af5 in main () at q.c:26
```

So your problem is in a call to **your** function `cmp` by the qsort library, that calls strcmp with bad pointers.

**So we go up from one stack frame**, to be at your cmp function level:

```
(gdb) up
#1  0x00000000004009b3 in cmp (p1=0x7ffffffeeb60, p2=0x7ffffffeeb88) at q.c:8
8           return strcmp( *(const char **) p1,  *(const char **) p2);
```

We look at the type of p1:

```
(gdb) ptype p1
type = void *
```

Since p1 is a pointer, we examine its content displaying 10 first bytes:

```
(gdb) print (*(char *) p1)@10
$43 = "jk\000\000\000\000\000\000\000"
```

So we discover it is a null terminated string containing  `jk`.

So your cast is invalid: `*(const char **) p1`.

This should have been `(const char*) p1`.

We change the cast and then it works.

Comment: Valgrind is pretty effective on this sort of thing, too - and is nicely non-interactive.

Answer (score 2):

`qsort()` passes to the compare function two pointers to the array's elements.

The array's elements are of type `char[255]`. So `qsort()`'s compare function gets passed in two `char(*)[255]`.

So it should look like

```
int cmp(const void *p1, const void *p2)
{
  const char (*ps1)[255] = p1;
  const char (*ps2)[255] = p2;

  return strcmp(*ps1, *ps2);
}
```

Comment: Would be nasty function if OP wanted to change array size, right?

Comment: _warning: initialization discards 'const' qualifier from pointer tar
get type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]_

Comment: `const char (*ps1)[255] = p1;` makes the [same warning](https://ideone.com/Ubo0r7).

Comment: BTW, `&s[X][0]` is passed as an argument of the comparison function. It has no type information as it is passed as a void pointer. You try to reproduce the type but eventually that information is not used. You try to reproduce the type but eventually that information is not used. (Passed to `strcmp` as `const char *`) So it's just a form. It may be useful when using `strncmp` like `strncmp(*ps1, *ps2, sizeof(*ps1))`. However, since it means that it is useful as it is broken as C-String, it will be different from OP's desire.

Answer (score 0):

```
char s[255][255];
```

This smells very bad. Use [C dynamic memory allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation).

Consider instead a heap-allocated pointer to an array of heap-allocated strings.

```
qsort(s, n , sizeof(char *), cmp);
```

Read carefully the documentation of [qsort(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/qsort.3.html). With a `char s[255][255]` your call to `qsort` is *very* wrong.

> Anyone can give me some suggestions?

Read more carefully a good C programming book and the documentation of every function you are using (even [strcmp(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcmp.3.html)). Look also at some [C reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c) and glance into the C11 specification [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf).

Compile with all warnings and debug info, i.e. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) (read more about [Invoking GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html#Invoking-GCC)). **Use the debugger** `gdb` (read about [*Debugging with GDB*](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/))

PS. We won't do your homework.

Comment: Can you recommend a good shorter guide to learn the _basics_ of GDB first before moving on to bigger things than _Debugging with GDB_?

Comment: No. That thing has an introductory chapter. Read it. Also, tons of tutorials on GDB available elsewhere. GIYF.